# Outlook Add-in: questions about calling EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js

We have an Outlook office.js API add-in that customizes meetings using a task pane the user opens from an add-in command while editing a meeting. We need information from the meeting that is not exposed by the office.js API. We can use the Outlook REST API or the Microsoft Graph API for our Office 365 users, but for those users on Exchange 2013+ On-Premise I believe we need to use EWS (correct?).

This is new to me so if I may, I have some questions:

1. I [read](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/outlook/1.4/Office.context.mailbox.md) that "The server administrator must set OAuthAuthentication to true on The Client Access Server EWS directory to enable the makeEwsRequestAsync method to make EWS requests." This seems like a serious limitation. Is there anyway around this? We want the add-in to be completely user-installable.
2. All the examples I've seen make use of makeEwsRequestAsync. What is ewsUrl used for? Can someone point me to an example?
3. Can someone recommend some good links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `OAuthAuthentication` enabled, there would be no way authenticate the user. Keep in mind that your add-in is running on *your web server*. Outlook uses OAUTH to authenticate the user and allow your web app to make an EWS request on that user's behalf.

The most common use of the `ewsUrl` is to [get attachments of an Outlook item from the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item).

Comment: Are you saying that if I want to make build a plugin using ews, I need to buy an exchange server. Is there a easier way

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The Outlook plugin framework uses JavaScript and works with all modern versions of Exchange, Exchange Online/M365, and Outlook.com.

Comment: In order to use oauthentication to true, you need a on premise excange server. The command to set oauthentication is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access-servers/set-webservicesvirtualdirectory?view=exchange-ps. I was trying to use office.js to write a plugin, and I confused office.js to be only used for plugins

Comment: You only need to set `OAuthAuthentication`  on on-prem Exchange. If you're using Exchange Online then it's already enabled.

Comment: I just used my online exchange server, and it gives the same accessRestricted Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'. Do you have any documentation that supports your claim of online exchange server supporting oauth or any thoughts on a solution to this error.

Comment: I create a new question if you have want to provided an answer for the community https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451273/do-you-need-an-on-premise-exchange-server-to-call-makeewsrequestasync/61451620#61451620.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Apologies for reviving an old thread. I am not very familiar with Exchange but am a seasoned web application developer.

We developed a plugin that works just fine for the attachment purposes using EWS + OAUth, however only after deploying we were informed the user is using on-prem 2016, their vendor mentioned that "OAuth with a hybrid config is not possible".

What are my options to retrieve attachments from on-prem without writing a COM add-in that runs on the exchange server?