# Do you need an on premise exchange server to call makeEwsRequestAsync?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an add in for outlook using office.js. For a week now, I have been receiving accessRestricted error from using [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#makeewsrequestasync-data--callback--usercontext-). When I read the documentation again, it says I have to explicitly set oauthentication to true in the exchange server. When I check to see how to set oauthentication to true, at the top of the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access-servers/set-webservicesvirtualdirectory?view=exchange-ps), I see the command only exist in on-premise exchange server.
I bought an online exchange server, and the command listed does not work in my environment. I have been complaining to microsoft that they should have put this information at the front, but someone from microsoft message me and said that oauthentication is set to true automatically when using exchange online. This appears to be false because I receive the same error using my administrator account of exchange online. I have posted the error message below. It seems obvious that the error message has something to with improper configurations, but I have also posted my code below.

[image: picture of the error messages]

```
 function getCreateFolderXMLRequest(request) {
  /*
  example request parameter
  <t:Folder>
    <t:DisplayName>Folder1</t:DisplayName>
  </t:Folder>
  <t:Folder>
    <t:DisplayName>Folder2</t:DisplayName>
  </t:Folder>
  */

  var completeRequest =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ "' +
    '               xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
    "      <soap:Body>" +
    '          <CreateFolder xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">' +
    "              <ParentFolderId>" +
    '                  <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="msgfolderroot"/>' +
    "              </ParentFolderId>" +
    "              <Folders>" +
    request +
    "              </Folders>" +
    "          </CreateFolder>" +
    "      </soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";

  return completeRequest;
}

export default function createFolders(listOfFolders, callback) {
  const folderHeader = "<t:Folder> <t:DisplayName>";
  const folderFooter = "</t:DisplayName> </t:Folder>";
  var xmlFolders = [];
  for (var folderName of listOfFolders) {
    xmlFolders.push(folderHeader + folderName + folderFooter);
  }

  const folderXMLRequest = getCreateFolderXMLRequest(xmlFolders.join(" "));
  Office.onReady(() => {
    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(folderXMLRequest, callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: OAuth should be enabled for exchange online servers by default. Can you try your request via postman https://developer.mypurecloud.com/api/rest/postman/index.html to confirm if its enabled.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT how am I supposed to that. The url has been abstracted away with the function makeEwsRequestAsync.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I just spent 8 hours yesterday debugging it with no progress. We connected into the exchange sever via powersehll, and gave ews privledges to the entire orginazation and mac os outtook and it still does not work. Even in your sample (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-MakeEWSRequest), you say that you require an on premise exchange server.

Comment: After some debugging, we found certain issues in the XML request. Please remove the extra space  in  first  url after "envelope/" and also replace "https" with "http" in the remaining URLs. Let us know if this resolve the issue you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

I would say yes because the documentation provides two ways of settings oauth and both explicitly states it has to be an on premise exchange server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services#authentication-and-permission-considerations-for-makeewsrequestasync